# deadlock, when different fields of a mutex guarded struct are accessed accross multiple methods

Tags: rust, mutex, deadlock

How to avoid deadlock when different fields of a mutex guarded struct are accessed across multiple functions like below

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Default)]
struct InnerData {
    ia: i32,
    ib: i32,
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct OuterData {
    oa: i32,
    ob: Mutex<InnerData>,
}

impl OuterData {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("fn foo begin");
        let b_mg = &mut self.ob.lock().unwrap();
        b_mg.ib = 5;
        println!("fn foo end");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut outer_data: OuterData = Default::default();
    let b_mg = &mut outer_data.ob.lock().unwrap();
    b_mg.ia = 3;

    if b_mg.ia == 3 {
        outer_data.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you Google for `rust mutex reentrant` you'll find a lot of good discussion.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart good discussions perhaps but ultimately not very helpful (on it's own) for OP since a reentrant lock can't grant mutability.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can change it to the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut outer_data: OuterData = Default::default();
    let mut b_mg = outer_data.ob.lock().unwrap(); // own the MutexGuard to be able to drop it
    b_mg.ia = 3;

    if b_mg.ia == 3 {
        drop(b_mg); // unlock the Mutex before calling foo()
        outer_data.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a correct solution though, depending on the actual use case. This could introduce a time-of-check time-of-use (TOCTOU) error because if you drop the mutex, `ia` might no longer be 3 when `foo` is called.